# yii delete all query cache

Tags: php, yii, memcached

I am using Yii 1.14 on centos 5 with php 5.2.4. I am doing query caching like `Projects::model()->cache(timeout,dependancy)->findAll(array())`. Now I have many of these. is there a way to clear all the query cache of this application. i cannot seem to find any info of adding these cache queries to a group and then delete the group from the cache. The problem is i have many applications using memcache and i do not want to flush it every time before a update. I only want to clear all cache related to this application.

**Updated**
I would like to flush the app cache on the beginning and end of update. i have no file beginning with `cache` in that location

```
 ll paradox/protected/runtime/
total 164
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 155571 Jun  3 15:53 application.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache   4096 Jun  4 11:53 gii-1.1.12
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache   4096 Jun  4 11:53 gii-1.1.14
```

Looking at the logs the `Yii::app()->cache->flush` does following

```
<28 new auto-negotiating client connection
28: Client using the ascii protocol
<28 get ns9e5np1ss92i7mqkjues577o1
>28 sending key ns9e5np1ss92i7mqkjues577o1
>28 END
<39 version
>39 VERSION 1.4.5
<39 flush_all
>39 OK
```

That looks like it clears all the memcache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete all cache data, use `flush()` method:

```
Yii::app()->cache->flush();
```

To delete all expired cache data, use `gc()` method:

```
Yii::app()->cache->gc();
```

Another way:

```
//if you use CFileCache
$cache=new CFileCache();
$cache->flush();
//if you use CMemCache
$cache2=new CMemCache();
$cache2->flush();
```

To find all related methods, take a look at the Yii Official document:

- [Caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview)
- [CFileCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileCache)
- [CMemCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMemCache)
- [CApcCache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApcCache)

Note that, the flush method, only flushes current running app cache values.

Comment: this would not clear all data in memcache? also is there a way to cache queries under a group, so i can delete the group from cache instead of all app cache?

Comment: Of course it does not delete others, since each application has its own KEY to create|access cache. If you are not sure, testing takes only 5 minutes, run a new clean Yii application and create cache, and try to remove it outside of application.

Comment: Take a look at the following link please: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCache#keyPrefix-detail - This is the key I said.

Comment: @sharif well, You made me doubtful :) but, I'm quite sure that it will remove its own application related caches. I suggest you test it on a VM.

Comment: @sharif Dear, did `flush()` remove other memcache data?

Comment: i have tested this using telnet and it deletes everything in cache.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the method **flush()** deletes everything or not depends on the type of Caching that you have enabled. To understand better you may have to dig deeper into the code of respective Class files.

So, basically the class `CCache` provides the method `flush` which in-turn calls the method 'flushValues' of the respective cacheClass.

1. [CDbCache](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/caching/CDbCache.php#L308) - Method 'flushValues' removes the data from table 'cacheTable' - Hence Cache data is separate for separate application.
2. [CFileCache](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/caching/CFileCache.php#L117) - Removes the files from the directory 'runtime'. Hence cache data is separate for separate application.
3. [CApcCache](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/caching/CApcCache.php#L104) - Removes the entire cache data from APC repo. Hence the cached data from other applications also will be removed
4. [CMemCache](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.16/framework/caching/CMemCache.php) - It doesn't implement the method `flushValues`. Hence if you call the method `flush` while using the MemCache, you'll see the Exception which is defined in the 'CCache' Class.

Answer (score 0):

if you need it after update s/ redeploy an option is to manually deleting  the file:
 `/protected/runtime/cache-1.1.xx.db`

Comment: interesting. does this delete/invalidate all application cache so it will recache?

Comment: @bonez only "Dev" cache, like DB used for Gii relations etc.
the front-end cache  (css, js ...) is located in /assets

Answer (score 0):

use command line

```
php yii cache/flush
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 0):

use comand line

```
./yii cache/flush-all
```

or

```
php yii cache/flush-all
```